# Add a filter menu to the list page

Tags: list, flow, sharepoint-list-filter

I created Sharepoint - List as a stock list. I have a button in the column that sends a request for an item and at the same time adds a reserved flag to the item.

As a result of the search, `executeFlow` does not work. That's why I'm looking for another solution.

Is there a way to create a search item using a filter?

Something like this:
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards

Frantisek

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to filter certain column or do list search?

Comment: I would like to search using a filter. Because the filter allows `executeFlow`, the search does not.